# ReactJS - Accessing Methods of Children (without using refs)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access the methods of a children in the parent Component.

First I wanted to use refs instead of this.props.children, but refs are only accessable when using them IN my component.

When using this, it seems not to be possible:

```
<Parent>
   <Child ref="testChild" />
</Parent>
```

In my Parent Component I am not able to access `this.refs.testChild` - because of this I have to access this component with `this.props.children`.

However: When accessing them with `this.props.children` I am not able to call methods of the child.

Example:

// Child.jsx

```
{
  customMethod() {},
  render() {... some stuff ...}
}
```

// Parent.jsx

```
{
   callChildrenMethods() {
       this.props.children.map((child)=>{
           console.log(child.props); // Props Object
           console.log(child.customMethod); // Undefined
       });
   },
   render() {return(<div>{this.props.children}</div>)}
}
```

As you can see: The customMethod is undefined. Is there any simple way to access the methods ? The better way would be to access the children with `refs` but this is not possible in my case.

Comment: What are you trying to do that isn't possible by passing down props from parent to child or using a store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props.children` is opaque, you should iterate using [React.Children](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children) API. Anyways, here's a fiddle which uses some hackery to invoke the child methods -
https://jsfiddle.net/sukantgujar/4bffu7tw/3/
Basically you need to access the type object of the child which points to the wrapped component instance.

```
var child = React.Children.only(this.props.children),
childType = child.type,
childProto = child.type.prototype,
childName = childProto.constructor.displayName,
childMethod = childProto.someMethod;
```

Comment: I am now using your solution and its working like I need it.

Comment: You would also want to add a type check to ensure you are calling method only on the right child.

Comment: Yes - I am doing this with comparing the displayName.

Answer (score 1):

You should let the child know through props:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        if(this.props.shouldRunChildrensMethod) {
            this.childsMethod();
        }

        return (...);
    }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            shouldRunChildrensMethod: false
        }
    },

    callChildrenMethods: function() {

        this.setState({
            shouldRunChildrensMethod: true
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <Child shouldRunChildrensMethod={this.state.shouldRunChildrensMethod} />
        );
    }

});
```

You can also view 2 way binding:

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Though this communication will be individually 1 by 1 with each child to parent.

Comment: In your case I have to add the Children in the render method - but I dont want to. The childen should be added by the developer in the views like he wants to. But maybe its possible to add props via this.props.children (i am able to access them, so maybe also to manipulate them)... I will give it a try. Thanks for the hint

Comment: @TimoRütten Actually the way I proposed you is the way Facebook advises to approach this problem, but you can see updated answer more other option

Comment: But when using Parents and Children in the way I did in my example above the typical way to access them methods would be like the other answer is showing - right ? Because with your solution its not possible to access them like this as I see