# Passing props to Higher-Order Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I have a higher-order component `FormBuilder` like this:

```
const FormBuilder = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class HOC extends React.Component {
    clearForm() { // ... }

    render() {
      return (
        <Form onSubmit={//what do I say here?!}>
           <Form.Input placeholder='Name' name='name' />
           <WrappedComponent clearForm={this.clearForm} />
        <Form>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the WrappedComponent `NewPizzaForm`:

```
class WrappedComponent extends React.Component {
  onSubmit() { // sends a POST request to the backend, then this.props.clearForm() }

  render() {
     return (
       <Form.Button>Add Pizza</Form.Button>
     );
  }
}

const NewPizzaForm = FormBuilder(WrappedComponent);

export default NewPizzaForm;
```

So I want to send the `onSubmit` function as a prop from the `WrappedComponent` to the `FormBuilder` so that it is available for call when the form is submitted. And the reason I decided to define the `onSubmit` function inside `WrappedComponent` is because I have another `WrappedComponent`(uses `FormBuilder`) that has the `onSubmit` function but it sends a PATCH request rather than POST request. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, formally a HoC is always a function that returns a component, not a component that returns another compoent

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini My `FormBuilder` is a function that is returning a component.

Comment: You're right, I've got a mistake reading multiple posts :)

Comment: Why don't you just define the submit function inside of `FormBuilder`?

Comment: @JossClassey The submit function is NOT generic, right? Imagine, `NewPizzaForm` does something completely different from `EditPizzaForm` when they are submitted.

Comment: The only thing I can think is to give `FormBuilder` a second argument specifically for it to handle `onSubmit`. I did think `refs` might be an option too, but I can't imagine how that would work. Please let me know if you figure it out though as I'm interested to see how you would do this!

Comment: Also maybe something like this could work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34302368/9636451

Answer (score 0):

You can act as following:

```
function logProps(InputComponent) {
  InputComponent.prototype.componentWillReceiveProps = function(nextProps) {
    console.log('Current props: ', this.props);
    console.log('Next props: ', nextProps);
  };
  // The fact that we're returning the original input is a hint that it has
  // been mutated.
  return InputComponent;
}

// EnhancedComponent will log whenever props are received
const EnhancedComponent = logProps(InputComponent);
```

---

As parameter you can add the prop "submit" to pass in the method.

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-mutate-the-original-component-use-composition

Answer (score 0):

I think we might need a little more information about the structure of your project, but you could create a function within FormBuilder (**funcA**) that you pass down to the WrappedComponent that takes a function as an argument. Then when you click the button within WrappedComponent, it would send its own onSubmit function back up to **funcA** where it can be used within FormBuilder.

This can then be used on your other WrappedComponent (with the POST request) as you would just be sending the onSubmit function from both to be called within FormBuilder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all sure if this would work, but maybe you could save the result of the form submission into the HOC's state, and then pass that information down to `WrappedComponent` via props. Then using `getDerivedStateFromProps` inside of `WrappedComponent`, you can pass the submitted form information into the component's submit function.